How to summarize the results of a game?
This is a problem I am working on:

Suppose Team Red and Team Blue play 5 games.
In each game, either team tries to grab all the cookies from a table and we see which team grabbed a greater percentage of cookies.
At the end, we see that Team Red won 4 games to
However, this does not provide any information on how close the games were.

Is there some other metric we could use that allows us to understand that even though Team Red won 4:1 ... how close the games were?
For example:

Scenario 1:  game 1, red 53%...game 2, red 51% ... game 3: red 54% ... game 4: red 51% ... game 5 : red 52%
Scenario 2:  game 1, red 99%...game 2, red 98% ... game 3: red 97% ... game 4: red 99% ... game 5 : red 98%

Even though Team Red won 5-0 in both scenarios, we can clearly see that the games were a lot closer in Scenario 1 vs Scenario 2.
Is there some metric which allows us to understand that Team Red won 5:0 and dominated all victories vs winning 5:0 and barely winning?


Idea 1: Two separate metrics. The first metric is 5-0, and the second metric would be something like this:

$$
  \text{Average Margin of Victory} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (\text{Red's %} - \text{Blue's %})
$$
where (N) is the number of games.

Scenario 1:
$$
  \frac{(53 - 47) + (51 - 49) + (54 - 46) + (51 - 49) + (52 - 48)}{5} = 3.2\%
$$

Scenario 2:
$$
  \frac{(99 - 1) + (98 - 2) + (97 - 3) + (99 - 1) + (98 - 2)}{5} = 96\%
$$


But can this information be jointly summarized into a single metric?


Idea 2:

$$
\text{Dominance Score} = W \times (1 + \frac{AMV}{100})
$$
Where:

$W$ is the number of wins (as a decimal, e.g., 4 out of 5 games = 0.8)

$AMV$ is the Average Margin of Victory (as a percentage)

The Dominance Score will always be between 0 and 2.

A score of 1 represents winning all games with an average 25% margin of victory.

Scores below 1 indicate either fewer wins or smaller margins of victory.

Scores above 1 indicate either more wins or larger margins of victory.


Here are some test cases:

Team wins all games (5-0) with small margins (AMV = 3.2%):
$\text{Dominance Score} = 1 \times (1 + \frac{3.2}{100}) = 1.032$

Team wins all games (5-0) with large margins (AMV = 96%):
$\text{Dominance Score} = 1 \times (1 + \frac{96}{100}) = 1.96$

Team wins 4 out of 5 games with moderate margins (AMV = 20%):
$\text{Dominance Score} = 0.8 \times (1 + \frac{20}{100}) = 0.96$




You've written a fairly lengthy Question, but it seems to signify a desire for your Readers to formulate a model/metric that meets your liking.  While mathematical and statistical model formulation is part of our toolcraft, it won't be clear to most Readers what criteria you intended.  At best it is unclear to me but others may be able to help you articulate some objectives to be met.

Why not do something simple and conventional like goal difference?
